# Laravel - minor data processing after getting Eloquent model instance

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I'm just beginning to learn Laravel and the MVC way of thinking, so please bear with me. How can I approach this, and is there a standard in where to put the processed data?

I would fetch for example, a `department_id` (e.g. `ABC`) and `personnel_number` (e.g. `1234`) from the database and **I want to piece them together as one** (e.g. `ABC1234`). So **I want to prepare an object property `code` after an `Eloquent` `Personnel` is prepared.**

Should I just alter the `Eloquent` object after it is created like:

```
$personnel = App\Personnel::find(1);
$personnel->code = $personnel->department_id . $personnel->personnel_number;
//or
$personnel->code(); //returns ABC1234
```

Or should I process the data in the `Personnel` model and fit everything into a new object? Like:

```
$personnel_data = new PersonnelData(App\Personnel::find(1));
//so I can access the personnel code using this, which is processed in constructor
$personnel_data->code;
//and access the model using this:
$personnel_data->model;
```

Or some other way?

There must be some general practice I can follow, because there are times when this is needed, e.g.:

- site URL when you only store a part of it, e.g. Google Drive file URL when you only have the file ids
- human readable time when you only store the timestamps
- person's full name when you store their first name and last name separately
- ...

Is there a common/standard way to prepare these beforehand and not process them only when you need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a property that is a concatenated string of other properties on the same model, then overload the attribute in the model:

```
public function getCodeAttribute() {
    return $this->department_id . $personnel->personnel_number;
}
```

Then you can just call `$personnel->code`